# Katalon Studio: Suppressing Alerts in Chrome Preferences

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, alert, lightning, katalon-studio

I'm trying to UI Test Salesforce Lightning with Katalon Studio, and with manual attention, it works, because I am always able to dismiss the Alert that wants to send me notifications (a standard when Lightning is used).
The Dismiss/Accept alert Steps don't work as they don't recognize the alert as part of the Website, so I would need to suppress them via preferences.

I have found [this chunk of code](http://learn-automation.com/disable-chrome-notifications-selenium-webdriver/) which I have tried to implement with a custom keyword, but to no avail. I also tried the firefox_profile way with a chrome_profile dictionary in the execution settings, putting the preference in the code chunk there, but that didn't help either.

I want to run Chrome headless with a Jenkins Job in the future and it seems I need to get this working somehow. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

While the problem at hand has not been solved, I realized that Alerts that aren't triggered by the Website such as "wants to send you notifications" have no influence on the clickability of Elements beneath it and they are not seen by Katalon Studio therefore. If it comes to it, you can best ignore them.